# NSAlert with NSTableview in it size issues

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nsalert

I have an NSAlert and I set its accessoryView to be an NSTableView. It works good with small-medium amounts of data, but when the row count is getting large, the tableview resizes instead of getting a scrollbar.
I would expect the table to only take up as much space as I give it in the Init frame.

```
 var alert = NSAlert()
 var sampleTable = NSTableView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 400, height:400))
 sampleTable.dataSource = self
 alert.accessoryView = sampleTable
 alert.beginSheetModal(...) // irrelevant code from here on
```

Comment: You need to enclose the NSTableView inside an NSScrollView.

Comment: That partially solves it. However, now anything outside of the NSScrollView is hidden as the NSTableView does not show a scrollbar and doesn't allow trackpad scrolling.

Comment: Is this still an alert or just a dialog?

Comment: OK, that helped. I am able to scroll through it using mousewheel/touchpad, but unfortunately, no scrolling bar appears. Is it possible to make it show up?
And it's an Alert with the accessoryview set to be a table for the user to deselect items from. Guess I am repurposing it to be a dialog. But I haven't found a dialog class by itself in Cocoa.

Comment: A dialog is a viewcontroller or window presented as a sheet or run modal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `scrolliew.autohidesScrollers = false` and `scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true` where scrollView is an NSScrollView instance